# put formatted output in a file, perl format

Tags: perl, format

If we set a specified format like this. Is there any way that we can copy the output and put it in a file.

ps: when i use strict, it shows "Global symbol "$counter" requires explicit package name at aggregator.pl line 19". What caused this? I have used local to define its scope, so i got a bit confused. Hope someone can give me a reponse. thx a lot

```
enter code here

# Setup includes
# use strict;
use XML::RSS;
use LWP::UserAgent;
# Declare variables for URL to be parsed
my $url2parse;
# Get the command-line argument
my $arg = shift;
# Create new instance of XML::RSS
my $rss = new XML::RSS;
# Get the URL, assign it to url2parse, and then parse the RSS content
$url2parse = get($arg);
die "Could not retrieve $arg" unless $url2parse;
$rss->parse($url2parse);
#create arrays to hold data
my @titles;
local $counter = 0;

#open file and write .txt output to it
open my $fh, ">output.txt" or die "File creation failed: $!";

# Print the channel items
foreach my $item (@{$rss->{'items'}}) {
     $titles[$counter] = $item->{'title'};
 &format_output($item->{'title'});
 $counter++;
}
sub get { 
    my $url = shift; 
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(); 
    my $res = $ua->get($url); 
    die ("Could not retrieve $url: " . $res->status_line) unless($res->is_success); 
    return $res->content; 
} 

sub format_output {
    local($title) = @_;
    $~ = "MYFORMAT";
    write;
    print $fh @_;
}
format MYFORMAT = 

=======================
  Title :~ ^<<<<<<<<<
$title
=======================
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` takes an optional filehandle parameter, so you could replace the `print` with `write $fh`.  You will need to use 1-parameter `select` in order to set `$~` for your filehandle as well as for `STDOUT`.

`local` does not declare the scope of a name, it just saves and restores a value on entry/exit of a scope.  Use `our` or `use vars` to declare the variable's scope.

Comment: Nice!, you really helped me out. Thank you very much

Comment: Use `our` and not `use vars` which is now considered _obsolete_.

Comment: @rainzwr On SO it is expected that you will "accept" the correct answer by clicking the checkmark just to the left of the answer. This marks it for future readers, and awards the rep points to the answerer.